# Is there any way to ignore application resources in contentpresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, styling

Some information related to problem: http://www.11011.net/archives/000692.html

Specific situation is : there is some generic textblock (key equals to type) styles declared in app.xaml which is in third party app, they used by all contentpresenters in my views ignoring my own styles.

I've found few possible solutions:

1. Explicitly assign all elements a style with overriden template & add resource dictionary with my styles to contentpresenter resources.
2. Add datatemplate for string, but there is a problem with access text detection ( may be solved by placing contentpresenter with ref to my own resources, isn't good solution because we increasing visual tree just to fix this problem)

Probably any other solutions?

P.S.: There is alot of views already exist, so first option is alot of work!

**To reproduce create new wpf project and modify next files:**

**App.xaml add generic style:**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml content is:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>     
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Hello world">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Access_Text"/>
                <MenuItem Header="NormalText"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>        
    <TextBlock Text="WELCOME TO BLACK MESA"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Add Dictionary.xaml resource dictionary and add next style inside:**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370809/wpf-how-to-override-an-application-wide-style-on-textblocks-on-specific-places), might be applicable.

Comment: great hint, but similar to 1st solution, profit in this case what we don't need to override all templates & can just lookup for child contentpresenters to add reference to own resource dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you might do it as I don't understand the structure of your App, but if you want to remove the style from the Application Resources you could do it programatically like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResourceDictionary dic = App.Current.Resources;
        dic[typeof (TextBlock)] = null;
    }
}
```

Using the XAML you provided in a test WPF project this leaves me with the default font size of **12** rather than **20**.

Comment: I don't want to modify app resources, because its third party host app ;)